# Generating Qt moc files in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, qt, moc

How to generate all the moc files in VS2019? I use VS terminal to generate moc files like "C:\moc path" somefile.h > moc_somefile.cpp one by one and then include to the project. Is there a way to create all the moc's in terminal? Or any other way to do this?

Comment: Use qmake or cmake to create your vcproj files and it's done for you. Otherwise no - you have to do it manually or add a custom build rule by yourself.

Comment: Do I need to add cmake or qmake in .pro file or what? How is the implementation?

Comment: I don't understand the question - a pro file is processed by qmake (see documentation) and a CMakeLists.txt file by cmake. What you use is up to you. There are enough documentation around for those two build systems.